# Is SeekableStream thread safe?

Tags: java, image, jersey, inputstream

I have a program that is supposed to resize an image. When I run it alone (call from JUnit), it works fine. But when I call it from inside a servelet (actually Jersey in a JUnit), it throws the following exception:

```
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/jai/codec/SeekableStream
```

The exception points to the line

```
SeekableStream seekableImageStream = SeekableStream.wrapInputStream(inputstream, true);
```

Does anyone have any fix?

TO CLARIFY AFTER SOME RESPONSES BELOW:

When I call the class from JUnit as follows it works:
    ResizeMyImage.smallImage(imageFilepath, thumbnailWidth);

But when I call it as below, then I get the error:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

If I remove the calls to ResizeMyImage from the larger program, the DefaultHttpClient ... works as well. Thanks.

Response to below: How do I verify that GlassFish is using a different JDK?

Comment: Is the JAI jars in the classpath of your webapp/servlet container ?

Comment: I created the ResizeMyImage class inside the package for the webapp. I am using netbeans. The imports work fine: it builds and deploys. When I run the class alone as a local application it runs fine. It only prints the error when I run it as part of the larger package and using DefaultHttpClient. Is there an additional way to add the jar to the classpath of the webapp container? Will you please show how?

Comment: All this means is that the proper libraries are referenced during development, but not during runtime from a servlet container  You're supposed to place 3.party jars that you use in the WEB-INF/lib/ folder of your webapp - but I'm not familiar enough with how you'll configure netbeans to neatly package this up for you.

Comment: This is not a 3rd party library. jai_codec.jar and jai_core.jar come with JDK 1.6. And I verify; they're there -- in the JDK, I mean. My server is GlassFish.

Comment: Oh? Then Glassfish is apparently using a different JDK version.

Comment: Thanks. How would I verify and fix that?

Comment: @tribal are you sure about that ? None of my JDK 6 nor JDK 7 installation have those jars. You might have them installed as extensions, and glassfish might not load those (or glassfish is running using the JDK and those jars are installed in the JRE)

Answer (score 0):

You only have to worry about an object being thread-safe if you have a reference to the object from two different threads. If it's not thread-safe you will have problems when two different threads try to use the object at the same time.

As others have pointed out NoClassDefFoundError means java can't find a class you are referencing in your code.

**EDIT**

JAI stinks for doing some things. A library such as [sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/sanselan/) may work better for you.